# Does `mt_rand` produces secure enough results for generating bearer tokens?

Tags: php, rest, authentication, bearer-token

For my clients I need to create bearer tokens in order to be able to authenticate into my API. Hence in order to create them the `random_bytes` came to my mind: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php

But on an implementation I have seen using the `mt_rand` instead specifically this piece of code is used:

```
function gen_bearerToken(int length): string
{
  $bearer="";
  $pool='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTUVWXYZ';
  for($i=0;i<$length;i++){
     $bearer .= substr($pool, mt_rand(0, strlen($pool) -1), 1);
  }

  return $bearer;
}
```

But as I see the `mt_rand` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php does not generate cryptographically-secure random bytes, hence I assume that weak easy-to-guess tokens will be generated.

Also history has proved ad-hoc solutions often fail at security rather that long-time established solutions. Am I wrong to worry or with a big enough length (>100) I will be fine security-wise?

Comment: Many attacks against weak PRNGs are mostly theoretical. In practice, will an attacker be interested enough in your specific service to attack it in such depth that attacking the weak PRNG will be their first or only attack vector…? Probably a) nobody will attack you specifically in that depth and b) there are probably other issues attackers would focus on first. If you *know* that `mt_rand` is weak, why even consider worrying about it instead of using a known good PRNG?

Comment: Consider using https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php